# Unable to scroll in Salesforce Mobile on iOS

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, ios

We have a Lightning Component action on that navigates to another component to collect user information through a form. It was working well on desktop and mobile (both iOS and Android), but users are unable to scroll in the Lightning component form on iOS now. I've tried `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` and `overflow: auto` too, but still doesn't scroll at all. Elements in the component respond to touches, but they are unable to scroll in iOS. Can someone help?